# How to get props value through drawer navigator

Tags: react-redux, react-native

How to get the userdata props value in head component ?I am mapping state to 
 props but not able to take that value in head component.How to pass this.
 Passing values to Higher order component.Provinding the code.Can someone
 please go through it. How to get the userdata props value in head component ?I am mapping state to 
 props but not able to take that value in head component.How to pass this.
 Passing values to Higher order component.Provinding the code.Can someone
 please go through it

```
import React from "react";
import {Image, Text, View, ToastAndroid} from "react-native";
import {createDrawerNavigator} from 'react-navigation-drawer';
import {createMaterialTopTabNavigator, createStackNavigator, createAppContainer,DrawerActions} from "react-navigation";
import {Icon} from 'react-native-elements';
import DrawerContent from "./DrawerContent";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import FirstList from "./FirstList";
import SecList from "./SecList";
import ThirList from "./ThirList";
import color from "../util/Colors";
import DashBoard from "./DashBoard";
const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
const TabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
{
    FirstList : FirstList ,
    SecList : SecList ,
},
{
    tabBarOptions: {
        labelStyle: {fontSize: 13},
        activeTintColor: color.basecolor,
        inactiveTintColor: 'black',
        scrollEnabled: false,
        style: {
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            height:45
        },
        indicatorStyle: {
            backgroundColor: color.basecolor,
        }
    },
    title: 'Details',
}

);
const StackNavigator1 = createStackNavigator({
TabNavigator: {
    screen: TabNavigator,
    navigationOptions:({navigation})=>{
        return{
            header: (
                <Head/>
            )
        }
    },
},
List: {
    screen: ThirList 
    navigationOptions:({navigation})=>{
        return{
            header: null
        }
    },
},
});
const RootNav = createAppContainer(StackNavigator1);
var name;
class Head extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    name='';
    var today = new Date();
    this.state = {
        'date': today.getDate() + " " + monthNames[today.getMonth()] + " " + today.getFullYear()
    };
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.props)+"userdata");
}

render() {
    const {date} = this.state;
    return (
        <View>
            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: color.mainback, height: 40,padding:10}}>
                <Text style={{
                    fontSize: 14,
                    textAlign: 'left',
                    marginLeft: 10,
                    flex:1,
                    color:color.textcolor,
                    fontWeight:'bold',
                    textAlignVertical: "center"
                }}>Orders</Text>
                <Text style={{
                    fontSize: 10,
                    textAlign: 'right',
                    marginLeft: 20,
                    marginRight: 20,
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    color:color.datetextcolor,
                    textAlignVertical: "center"
                }}>{date}</Text>
            </View>

        </View>
    );
}

}

class RootScreen extends React.Component {
render() {
    return (
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <RootNav/>
        </View>
    );
}
}

const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    DrawerNavigator: {
        screen: RootScreen,
        activeTintColor: color.basecolor,
        navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({title: 'Home'}, {
                headerLeft:
                    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', marginLeft: 20}}>
                        <Icon name="menu" onPress={()=>navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer())} size={30} color="white"/>
                        <Image source={require('../images/logo.png')}
                               style={{height: 35, width: 150, resizeMode: 'contain'}}/>
                    </View>,
            }
        ),
    },
    Dashboard: {
        screen: DashBoard,
        navigationOptions: {
            headerTitle: (
                <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                    <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                        <Image
                            source={require('../images/logo.png')}
                            style={{height: 35, width: 150, marginLeft: -20, resizeMode: 'contain'}}
                        />
                    </View>
                </View>
            ),
        },
    },
}, {

    defaultNavigationOptions: {
        headerTintColor: 'white',
        headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: color.basecolor,
        },
    }
}
);

const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
{
    Home: StackNavigator
},
{
    contentComponent: DrawerContent,
    drawerWidth: 280,
    navigationOptions: {
        header: null
    },

}
);
function mapStateToProps(state) {
return {
    userdata: state.auth.userdata
}
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps) (DrawerNavigator);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your aim is to connect *Head* component to *Redux Store*, right?

Simply using connect() function will suffice.
The solution would be to add this line of code.

`const NewHead = connect(mapStateToProps)(Head)`

Replace the `<Head/>` with `<NewHead/>` in *StackNavigator1*

Then, access the data within the *Head* component in the following manner.

`this.props.userdata`

**OR**

If you want to pass data to routes when you navigate to them, you can refer to this [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html).

Comment: I already tried this way :connect(mapStateToProps)(Head) .But userdata is not their in props in head component

Comment: See the edited answer. connect() doesn't modify the existing component. It returns a new component.